# Python: действия с элементами списка с условием

Tags: python, массивы, циклы, list, numpy

Как правильно написать условие: если в листе найдется отрицательное число, `к` нему добавляем число `g`?

```
import numpy as np
a = [-2,-1,0,1,2]
b = [-6,-5,1,2,3]
g = 1
for i,j in zip(a,b):
    if i and j < 0:
    # !тут проблема!   
        i + g
        j + g
print(a,b)
```

---

Чтобы результат был таким:

```
[-1,0,0,1,2] [-5,-4,1,2,3]
```

Comment: Уточните, условие должно быть, что если в двух списках на одинаковых позициях стоит отрицательное число, то нужно в этой позиции увеличить значение в обоих списках на g? Или списки проверяются независимо друг от друга?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если я правильно понял условие:

```
In [11]: a = np.array([-2,-1,0,1,2])

In [12]: b = np.array([-6,-5,1,2,3])

In [13]: a[a < 0] += g

In [14]: b[b < 0] += g

In [15]: a
Out[15]: array([-1,  0,  0,  1,  2])

In [16]: b
Out[16]: array([-5, -4,  1,  2,  3])
```